# 2 unknown fields Sent connection Name and Received connection name field in List views. Not sure whats the use of these 2 fields

Tags: community, administration

As a system admin, i restricted some fields using field level security however I see  2 unknown fields Sent connection Name and Received connection name field in List views. Not sure whats the use of these 2 fields. I cannot look for these fields on object

Can someone tell me why these fields are present on the list views?

Comment: Please [edit] this question to provide more context. It's quite difficult to help you without knowing exactly which list view or object you are looking at. What is the connection between these two fields and the FLS changes you made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sent Connection Name and Received Connection Name are related to Saleforce-to-Salesforce functionality. They allow users to see which orgs a record has been sent to or received from.